# How to lock MySQL resources while open in webform and release when closed / done editing

Tags: mysql, angular, laravel, locking

I'm building a platform that is supposed to serve many corporate users at the same time. The system contains a lot of records that from time to time require updating. It is important that every change is logged and appropriately stored. I use a Laravel 6 implementation for the back-end and Angular 6 for the front-end. The front-end sends requests to the back-end via HTTP requests. The data is stored in a MySQL database.

Users load a specific dataset in either read-only or in read-write mode. In read-only mode there is no need to lock the resource as the user is aware that he can only read the data. In read-write mode the dataset should be locked from the moment onwards that the user requested the data such that the dataset cannot be requested by a different user while someone is working on the data. The user working on the data then has the data open in a webform for editing. As soon as the user either saves, cancels or closes the browser the data should be unlocked.

Now locking the data in the database is not the problem, I keep a table of which datasets are locked for editing and whenever a user tries to access this data an error is thrown. Also releasing the data when the user either saves of cancels is not a problem, I just release the lock in the table.

However, since there is no interaction with the back-end when the browser is closed while editing, the dataset remains locked indefinitely (I could fix this with timestamps and cronjobs and so on but those are not an option for the company infrastructure). I'm wondering how to fix this?

One idea I had myself, but no idea on how to implement this, is to keep the HTTP connection open between the client and the server and have the server (laravel) execute some code to release the locks when the connection is closed. Any tips, hints or pointers for me to continue from here?

Comment: there must be some reason we aren't using an optimistic locking strategy which is more commonly used

Comment: Because it is not a locking at all. There are several business cases when a user needs to check out a piece of data and others must not touch it, while it is being edited.

Comment: @spencer7593, Yes, there is no use for the user to view the dataset when it's being edited by some other user since it's going to look totally different after saving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timestamp field without cron job to indicate how long a record is locked. If the current time is later than the timestamp, consider the record unlocked.

While the web form is open, you can use an ajax request every couple of minutes to update this timestamp for the next couple of minutes, thus keeping the record locked.

If the user closes the browser window, then the timestamp field does not get updated and the record will be unlocked in couple of minutes.

Comment: Do you see any possibilities to have it unlocked right away after the browser window is closed by means of the server signaling the connection is closed and then releasing the data?

Comment: I'm not aware of any reliable, cross browser method.